# Magento2 | How to change the main search site?

Tags: magento2, search

Sorry for my English

I currently have a full-text index and when the search is in progress, it does not look for a substring.

How to make a search to work as %LIKE%?

I have this

```
hdd with serial number: wcawf3605242model: wd5000aaks-75v0a0date: 04 mar 2010dcm: harchtjabnproduct of: thailandpcb sticker: 2061-701640-k02 05pd5pcb revision: 2060-701640-002 rev a
```

and when I enter V0, I want it to find him here. `wd5000aaks-75v0a0date`